# Comparing performance of ext4 and NTFS

Tags: c, linux, windows, benchmarking

I am doing benchmarking using C of ext4 and NTFS (on RHEL and Windows 7 respectively) as part of a class project.

I am trying to come up with experiments for the benchmarks but am very confused about what should be done and if what I'm thinking makes any sense (my prof is out for 2 weeks and the class has no TA). Here are the details with the questions in bold:

- Comparing sequential-read speeds: I plan to have a few files of different sizes and performing sequential reads on these with size of each read being a block (4K on both file systems). **Should I do this on files of different sizes or on the same file? Also, does it make sense to read in multiples of the block size?** Of course, for reads beyond the first caching would come into play.
- Comparing random-read speeds: Run reads (again of the block size) at different file offsets. **Again, same questions as above.**
- Comparing write speeds: Disable write caching on both and write in sizes of a block.

My main concern is with respect to the sizes of the files I run my tests on and the size to use for each operation (read/write).

Any other pointers with respect to what I could include in my experiments and any other changes required to my approach would be greatly appreciated.

I also plan to compare metadata operations but I'm working on those and will probably post a question later if needed.

Comment: Every single point in your list is far too broad, let along the whole question. You should do some research on your own and not expect others do your assignment.

Comment: @Olaf: Could you please tell me more on what I can make specific? I kept the question brief but I've already done a lot of research but am not able to progress owing to the questions I asked. And I'm not expecting anyone to do my assignment - I just need help with getting started.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you ask whether you should "read in the block size".

Comment: @Schwern: I mean read in multiples of the filesystem's block size. Now that you mention it, I should edit the question. It doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As benchmarks of filesystems, they will be invalid. There are too many variables. Assuming you'll use the same hardware, your variables are...

- Filesystem (ext4 vs NTFS)
- Operating system (Redhat vs Windows)
- C compiler (gcc/clang vs Visual C++ (I'm guessing))

What you're benchmarking *Redhat + their C compiler + ext4* vs *Windows + their compiler + NTFS*. ***No general statements about the filesystems can be drawn from this*** only about the combinations. You might want to point out this flaw in the homework for extra points, or it might just annoy the TA. Your call.

Redhat does have an NTFS implementation, so you could eliminate the variables by benchmarking everything on Redhat, but then you'll be benchmarking Redhat's NTFS implementation vs Redhat's ext4 implementation. This would have no bearing on Windows's NTFS implementation.

It's possible you could conduct extra tests to eliminate the compiler and operating system variables, but I don't know what they are.

---

Putting that aside, because this is homework, you ask about what scenarios to run. The answer is ***all of them***. Benchmarks are supposed to reflect real world usage, and in the real world you read and write files of different sizes and different caching states. Put them in a big matrix and run all combinations.

Generally, file size ranges should go from the block size all the way up to 4 gigs (simulating a video file). The more increments the better. Powers of 1024 would be a good start, three makes a curve. So 4K, 4M, 4G.

You should benchmark both with and without caching enabled to test how well the filesystem works when reading in an uncached file and when reading a cached file. Both represent real world scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Well I'll MingW on Windows and the hardware is the same but yeah - it'll have to be ext4 and NTFS. Although I'll check with the prof once he's back. What you described more or less coincides with that I had in mind. Any other tests than I can consider for performance of filesystem operations?

Comment: @Cygnus Yes, it's important to test how well it handles multiple reads and writes at the same time. It's no good if your filesystem can only be used by one program at a time. You can come up with all sorts of scenarios from all sequential reads, all small writes, but be sure to throw in one that chooses operations at random (use the same seed for both setups). Multithreading IO performance (vs multiprocess) is also important.

Comment: @Cygnus You'll also want to measure CPU and memory usage. A fast filesystem isn't any good if it's sucking down all your CPU and memory. Finally, cheat and look at what [iozone](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/iozone.1.html) does.

Comment: Since you can't actually build NTFS with GCC, or build ext4 unmodified with MSVC++, or run MS' NTFS under Linux, or run ext4 (again unmodified) under Windows, this seems like a moot point. I think it's perfectly valid to benchmark all indivisible parts of a system as a complete unit.

Comment: @LukeHutchison You can do that, but it must be framed as benchmarking Windows 7 with NTFS vs Redhat with ext4. Such a benchmark offers no easy conclusions about NTFS vs ext4. Is such a benchmark useful? Depends why you're doing it. Since this is for a class, being aware of the variables and working to eliminate or mitigate them is an important lesson.